# How Categories Images plugin maps images with term_id?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using `Categories Images` plugin in wordpress , i want to know that how they are connecting images with `term_id` i saw database of wordpress there is nothing happens in `postmeta` table, then how they are mapping `term_id` to images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are storing in the `wp_post` table, 
for Example if `option_name` column has `z_taxonomy_image_19` in this `19` is `term_id` and `z_taxonomy_image_` is for reference and `option` has `url` of that image